# Ant: What happens to properties set in antcall build files?

Tags: ant, build

I've got a build that's a mess. In the end, targets are executed up to 15 times. Most targets are executed over a dozen times. This is because the build and targets are divided into 10 separate build files (`build.xml`, `build-base.xml`, `compile.xml`, etc.).

In many build files, you have at the beginning  `<property>` tasks outside of all targets in the build file. These are usually executed first before any targets are called.

Here is my `build.xml` file:

```
 <import file="build-base.xml"/>

 [...]

 <target name="compile-base">
      <antcall target="setup-tmpj"/>
      <ant antfile="compile.xml" target="compile-base"/>
      [...]
 </target>
```

Here's the `compile.xml` file:

```
 <import file="build-base.xml"/>

 <property name="target" value="1.5"/>
 <available file="target/gensrc/com"   property=gensrc.exists"/>

 [...]

 <target name="buildAndCompileCodeGen" unless=gensrc.exists">
    <blah blah blah/>
 </target>

 <target name="compile-base" depends="buildAndCompileCodeGen">
     <blah blah blah/>
 </target>
```

I execute this:

```
$ ant -f build.xml compile-base
```

This calls the target `compile-base` in the `compile.xml` file. This is dependent upon the target `buildAndCompileCodeGen` in the `compile.xml` file. However, the target `buildAndCompileCodeGen` is only executed if the property `gensrc.exists` is unset.

In the `compile.xml` file is an `<available>` task that will set the `gensrc.exists` property, but this task is located outside of all targets in `compile.xml`. Is that `<available>` task ever called, so that `gensrc.exist` is set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I figured out what's going on...

Yes, when I call the `compile-base` target in the `compile.xml` file via the `<ant>` task, all tasks not under a target are executed before the target I call is executed. That means, if the code is already there, the `buildAndCompileCodeGen` target is called but not executed.

What I did was combine all the build files into one big file and got rid of all of the `<ant>` and `<antcall>` tasks. I had put the `<available>` task in the combined `build.xml` file.

In the original circumstance, I would first do a `clean`, then call `compile-base` in the `compile.xml` file. At that time, the `<available>` task would run. Since I did a clean, the file didn't exist, the property `gencode.exists` isn't set, and `buildAndCompileCodeGen` target would run.

When I combined everything, the `<available>` task would run, set the `gencode.exists` property. Then, when I did a `clean`, I would delete the generate code. However, the `buildAndCompileCodeGen` target still wouldn't execute because `gencode.exists` has already been set.

What should be done is this:

```
 <target name="compile-base"
     depends="buildAndCompileCodeGen">
     <echo>Executing compile-base</echo>
 </target>

 <target name="buildAndCompileCodeGen"
     depends="test.if.gencode.exists"
     unless="gencode.exists">
     <echo>Executiing buildAndCompileCodeGen</echo>
 </target>

 <target name="test.if.gencode.exists">
     <available file="${basedir}/target/gensrc/com"
         property="gencode.exists"/>
 </target>
```

In this case, I call `compile-base`. That will call `buildAndCompileCodeGen`. That will first call `test.if.gencode.exists` first. This will be done even if the property `gencode.exists` already is set. Dependent clauses are run on targets before Ant looks at the `if` or `unless` parameters. This way, I don't set `gencode.exists` until I am ready to execute the `buildAndCompileCodeGen` target. Now, the available task will be run **after** I do a clean.